# How to solve java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate named parameter [enteredValue], expecting one of [] in Hibernate 5.4.15 Final?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hql

This is my StudentDaoImpl class.

```
package com.gavs.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;

import com.gavs.beans.Result;
import com.gavs.beans.Student;
import com.gavs.hibernate.until.HibernateUtil;

public class StudentDaoImpl implements StudentDao {




    @Override
    public List<Result> showRecords(Student s) {

        System.out.println("student name is:"+s.getName());

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

                session.beginTransaction();

String hql="select s from com.gavs.beans.Student s where s.name = :nameparam";

      System.out.println(hql);

        Query q = session.createQuery(hql);
        q.setParameter("nameparam",s.getName());



        List<Student> r1= q.list(); 


        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();        
        return rl;
    }


}
```

This is error message displayed :

```
Type Exception Report

Message Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate named parameter [nameparam], expecting one of []

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate named parameter [nameparam], expecting one of []
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate named parameter [nameparam], expecting one of []
    org.hibernate.query.internal.ParameterMetadataImpl.getNamedParameterDescriptor(ParameterMetadataImpl.java:229)
    org.hibernate.query.internal.ParameterMetadataImpl.getQueryParameter(ParameterMetadataImpl.java:198)
    org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingsImpl.getBinding(QueryParameterBindingsImpl.java:188)
    org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:490)
    org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:111)
    com.gavs.dao.StudentDaoImpl.showRecords(StudentDaoImpl.java:41)
    com.gavs.controllers.StudentControl.getStudentDetail(StudentControl.java:37)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

Here is the error that occurred when I  debug the code,

```
Jun 03, 2020 12:18:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.31
Jun 03, 2020 12:18:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Feb 5 2020 19:32:12 UTC
Jun 03, 2020 12:18:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version number: 9.0.31.0
Jun 03, 2020 12:18:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 8.1
Jun 03, 2020 12:18:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.3
Jun 03, 2020 12:18:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Jun 03, 2020 12:18:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre
Jun 03, 2020 12:18:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_31-b13
Jun 03, 2020 12:18:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Jun 03, 2020 12:18:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         F:\VCM\JpaSpring\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Jun 03, 2020 12:18:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         D:\BACKUP 19.03.2020\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.31
Jun 03, 2020 12:18:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:65187
Jun 03, 2020 12:18:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -javaagent:E:\eclipse1\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\418\0\.cp\lib\javaagent-shaded.jar
Jun 03, 2020 12:18:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=F:\VCM\JpaSpring\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Jun 03, 2020 12:18:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=D:\BACKUP 19.03.2020\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.31
Jun 03, 2020 12:18:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=F:\VCM\JpaSpring\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Jun 03, 2020 12:18:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=D:\BACKUP 19.03.2020\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.31\endorsed
Jun 03, 2020 12:18:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Jun 03, 2020 12:18:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.23] using APR version [1.7.0].
Jun 03, 2020 12:18:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
Jun 03, 2020 12:18:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
Jun 03, 2020 12:18:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019]
Jun 03, 2020 12:18:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jun 03, 2020 12:18:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Server initialization in [1,800] milliseconds
Jun 03, 2020 12:18:57 PM org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory getObjectInstance
WARNING: Name = CRUDCode Property maxActive is not used in DBCP2, use maxTotal instead. maxTotal default value is 8. You have set value of "100" for "maxActive" property, which is being ignored.
Jun 03, 2020 12:18:57 PM org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory getObjectInstance
WARNING: Name = CRUDCode Property maxWait is not used in DBCP2 , use maxWaitMillis instead. maxWaitMillis default value is -1. You have set value of "10000" for "maxWait" property, which is being ignored.
Jun 03, 2020 12:18:57 PM org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory getObjectInstance
INFO: Name = CRUDCode Ignoring unknown property: value of "CRUDCode" for "global" property
Jun 03, 2020 12:18:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Jun 03, 2020 12:18:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.31]
Jun 03, 2020 12:19:02 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jun 03, 2020 12:19:02 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
WARNING: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [338] milliseconds.
Jun 03, 2020 12:19:20 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jun 03, 2020 12:19:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Jun 03, 2020 12:19:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'studentDetails'
Jun 03, 2020 12:19:20 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: Initializing Servlet 'studentDetails'
Jun 03, 2020 12:19:23 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: Completed initialization in 2866 ms
Jun 03, 2020 12:19:23 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jun 03, 2020 12:19:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in [25,979] milliseconds
Student name is  Vishnu
Jun 03, 2020 12:28:17 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.17.Final
Jun 03, 2020 12:30:51 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
Jun 03, 2020 12:31:09 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Jun 03, 2020 12:31:10 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/initialdb]
Jun 03, 2020 12:31:10 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
Jun 03, 2020 12:31:10 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Jun 03, 2020 12:31:10 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Jun 03, 2020 12:32:24 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator initiateService
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : null
Jun 03, 2020 12:32:26 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
Jun 03, 2020 12:32:29 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
Jun 03, 2020 12:32:30 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Jun 03, 2020 12:35:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [studentDetails] in context with path [/HibernateWithQuery] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]] with root cause
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:961)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1363)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1391)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.performTlsHandshake(ExportControlled.java:336)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.performTlsHandshake(StandardSocketFactory.java:188)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.performTlsHandshake(NativeSocketConnection.java:99)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:325)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.connect(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:164)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.connect(NativeProtocol.java:1342)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:157)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:956)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.addConnections(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:331)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:228)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections$Builder.build(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:369)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:473)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:689)
    at com.gavs.hibernateutil.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:23)
    at com.gavs.dao.StudentDaoImpl.showRecords(StudentDaoImpl.java:23)
    at com.gavs.controllers.StudentControl.getStudentDetail(StudentControl.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:688)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Also I want to mention that this is a dynamic web application where I have put the hibernate.cfg.xml file in the WEB-INF/classes folder within the WebContent folder. This is  A Spring MVC and hibernate project. 
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem with the application. I have used Spring MVC and hibernate in my web application. As I'm trying to integrate Spring with Hibernate, I  used the LocalSessionFactoryBean in my applicationContext.xml instead of using hibernate.cfg.xml file. This solved the issue.

Here is the applicationContext.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"

    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

       <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.gavs" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <bean 
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

     <!-- Step 1: Define Database DataSource / connection pool -->

    <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/initdb"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="root"/>
</bean>

    <!-- Step 2: Setup Hibernate session factory -->

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.gavs.beans" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 3: Setup Hibernate transaction manager -->

    <bean id="myTransactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 4: Enable configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager" />

    <bean id="stud" class="com.gavs.dao.StudentDaoImpl">
    </bean>


    </beans>
```

By adding these beans to applicationContext.xml, the SessionFactory can be injected in the required class and used. So there is no need of hibernate.cfg.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

```
String hql="select new com.gavs.beans.Result(s.name as s_name,s.age as s_age,d.dept_name as d_name,c.college_name as c_name)"+
        " from com.gavs.beans.College c" + 
        "join com.gavs.beans.Department d on d.institutes.college_id = c.college_id" + 
        "join com.gavs.beans.Student s on s.departments.dept_id = d.dept_id" + 
        "where s.name = :enteredValue";
```

You have a missing space between `dept_id` and `where s.name` and a few other places (almost all lines are missing a blank character at the end). This probably plays a role in your issue. Consider storing your queries as resources (files) and read them from your code. Building SQL strings in another language is not very elegant (can be alright for simple queries).

The same query with corrected spaces:

```java
String hql=
        "select new com.gavs.beans.Result(s.name as s_name,s.age as s_age,d.dept_name as d_name,c.college_name as c_name)"+
        " from com.gavs.beans.College c" + 
        " join com.gavs.beans.Department d on d.institutes.college_id = c.college_id" + 
        " join com.gavs.beans.Student s on s.departments.dept_id = d.dept_id " + 
        " where s.name = :enteredValue";
```

Comment: What's your new query? Please update it in your question

Comment: It's the same query which you have given.

Comment: As you said I left  blank spaces in the query. I have updated the query in the question.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you updated it. Can you also please remove the code that's not useful? It's cluttering the question.

Comment: I have updated the question Dici.  I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't get you. You didn't add the spaces as I recommended. If you print your query with `System.out.println`, here's what you will see: `select new com.gavs.beans.Result(s.name as s_name,s.age as s_age,d.dept_name as d_name,c.college_name as c_name) from com.gavs.beans.College cjoin com.gavs.beans.Department d on d.institutes.college_id = c.college_idjoin com.gavs.beans.Student s on s.departments.dept_id = d.dept_idwhere s.name = :enteredValue`. As you can see, this is not valid SQL and there are missing spaces in several places

Comment: Now I corrected the statement , but still the error persists

Comment: In this application I have used  @OneToMany  relations. Can we use join if the entities have  OneToMany  relations?  Just asking whether that could be the problem...

Comment: You say you corrected it but the code in your question isn't correct so how could we be able to help?

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't identify the problem Dici. Can you please tell me  which part of the code is incorrect ?

Comment: Well since the query in your question still doesn't contain the spaces I told you were missing, I can't be sure of what code you executed so I can't discard my initial hypothesis. As far as I'm concerned, it's still possible that the root cause is the missing spaces. I'm not sure why you haven't added them yet but I'll put a query with the correct spaces in my answer

Comment: I  have updated the query in my question  that contains the spaces now

Comment: Then I'd recommend using the debugger and see how the query gets parsed and why it doesn't detect the named parameter

Comment: Okay, I use the debugger

Comment: Hi Dici. I changed my Hql query  as "select s from Student s where s.name= :keyword"  and then run my code. But still I go the same error. Then I debugged the code, it  gave me  this "ERROR: Communications link failure" which I have posted in my question.

Comment: My web application is a Spring mvc+maven application. I want to use hibernate in this application  for database operations . I haven't done any Spring mvc and hibernate Inegration. But I have the hibernate.cfg.xml file.

Comment: Will the program work  only if  the integration is done ?

Comment: I'm not sure I can help from there, sorry

Comment: My  program worked Dici.  Thank you everybody for your help.

Comment: Cool, happy for you :p thanks for writing an answer for future users

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the keyword **as** from your hql and have a try?

```
String hql="select new com.gavs.beans.Result(s.name,s.age,d.dept_name,c.college_name )"+
                " from com.gavs.beans.College c" + 
                " join com.gavs.beans.Department d on d.institutes.college_id = c.college_id" + 
                " join com.gavs.beans.Student s on s.departments.dept_id = d.dept_id" + 
                " where s.name = :enteredValue";
```

Comment: String hql="select new com.gavs.beans.Result(s.name,s.age,d.dept_name,c.college_name)"+
          " from com.gavs.beans.College c  "+
          "join com.gavs.beans.Department d on d.institutes.college_id = c.college_id " + 
          "join com.gavs.beans.Student s on s.departments.dept_id = d.dept_id " + 
          "where s.name = :enteredValue";
  
 
       Query<Result> rs= session.createQuery(hql);   I tried this but still it shows the same error